# Turn a given column of objects from each dataframe in a list of dataframes into a float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

So, I am very new to Python. I have a list of 76 dataframes called df_clean. Each dataframe has columns that are objects. One column is called "OIL PROD" and I want to change all the numbers under it into a float for each dataframe and then sum them and make a list of those sums.  I have been trying this but it spits out an error.

```
oil_sum = []
for df in df_clean:
    oil_sum.append(df["OIL PROD"].astype("float").sum())
```

Spits out key error

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of your data nor any of the code that you have written that produces your problem. Please review Jon Skeet's excellent blog post [WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) for guidance in updating your question.  For a more detailed tutorial on asking a good question see Eric S. Raymond's site [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Answer (score 1):

Are the data frames all exactly the same? If the columns vary you could add a try/except block that returns 0 if the column name isn't found:

```
import numpy as np
oil_sum = [] 
for df in df_clean: 
    try:
        oil_sum.append(df["OIL PROD"].astype("float").sum())
    except KeyError:
        oil_sum.append(np.nan)
```

Edit: np.nan would probably be better than 0.0, to show you which data frames didn't have that column as opposed to columns that actually sum to 0.0

Comment: Thanks. I discovered that a couple were not the same and fixed the problem.